# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error: (Compiling 32 bit code on 64 bit machine)

Tags: 18.04, compiling, 64-bit, gcc, 32-bit

I want to execute a 32-bit assembly code, and I am using gcc for linking my object file (created by NASM) to an executable.

I have already tried methods stated in the post [Linking an assembler program: error “undefined reference to `printf'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374591/linking-an-assembler-program-error-undefined-reference-to-printf).

Executable is created but whenever I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
-bash: ./asmTest: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I have used the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf -g asmTest.asm
gcc -m32 asmTest.o -o asmTest
```

I have installed the Multilib version of gcc so that I can run 32-bit code on 64-bit machine.

I am using NASM version 2.13.02 and Ubuntu app (available for Windows, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS).

GCC version: gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

Please help.

**EDIT**

```
strace ./asmTest
```

gives the following output:

```
execve("./asmTest", ["./asmTest"],  0x7fffd49a5000 /* 19 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0660, st_rdev=makedev(4, 1), ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
getpid()                                = 1110
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Hmm... the 32-bit "Hello World" example from [here](https://gist.github.com/yellowbyte/d91da3c3b0bc3ee6d1d1ac5327b1b4b2) works for me (18.04 w/ gcc 7.5.0) although I needed to add `-nostartfiles` to the gcc command. Does `strace ./asmTest` throw any light? what about `readelf`?

Comment: @steeldriver I checked with -nostartfiles option. Still gives that same error. I have edited my question to include ```strace ./asmTest``` (It gives some kind of error, I don't know what that means)

Comment: Hmm.. so strace doesn't really tell you any more than you already know. What does `file asmTest` think the format is? what is your host machine info (`uname -a`)?

Comment: @steeldriver ```file asmTest``` gives ```ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=8714423620f39ebb6284ff40ff86cc86f75ecad1, not stripped``` and  machine info ```Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #476-Microsoft Fri Nov 01 16:53:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux```

Comment: OK... so is this on WSL rather than a regular Ubuntu system? If so, it's likely nothing to do with `nasm` or `gcc`, it's simply that Microsoft WSL doesn't support the 32-bit ABI. See for example [multilib ABIs don't work #711](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/711)

Comment: @steeldriver Is there any work-around for this situation?

Answer (score -1):

I am having problems running hello_world.c, compiled for 32 machine, on Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit OS.  No problems when run natively.  Here is my process for creating the executable:

`gcc -march=i386 -m32 hello_world.c -S -o hello_world.s`
`as --32 hello_world.s`

as invokes the linker and generates a 32 bit executable image.

```
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$ 
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$ ./a.out
bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$ ls -l ./a.out
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jeffs jeffs 1476 Oct 28 15:24 ./a.out
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$
```

I have read several articles, most of which seem antiquated.  So I have tried:

```
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$ arch
x86_64
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$ sudo apt-get install multiarch-support
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package multiarch-support is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'multiarch-support' has no installation candidate
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$ 
jeffs@jeffs-desktop:~/VarsityTutors$
```

I am doing this project for a friend who is taking a class in assembler as part her CS degree.